# How to configure IIS URL Rewrite module to work with "HTML 5 pushState" style and hash fragments on url?

Tags: angularjs, angular, iis, url-rewriting

Angular 2 has a *PathLocationStragy* to work with html5 routes and a *HashLocationStrategy* to work with hash fragments '#' on routes.

The issue here is when we use OIDC (OpenID Connect) for user authentication and *PathLocationStragy* (or *html5mode* for routes on AngularJS) because OpenID on some flows returns data after a '#' fragment after redirect back to the site after user logging with a url as follow:
`http://mysite/callback#code=7b60c0570d7c4da0fc60678c0e46deadd5eeab0a659203fd44efb7cd51b2cdab&id_token=eyJhb ...`

For html5 routes is very common the settings bellow on IIS Url Rewrite:

`...
    <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <remove name="AngularJS Routes" />
          <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/(api)/" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
...`

But when the web sever receives the url with `http://mysite/callback#code=7b60c0570d7c4d` from Authorization Server after user logging the response for this request is: `403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.`

I think that the problem is with the Url rewrite settings, not with AngularJS or Angular 2 app´s...
How to solve that? How to use AngularJS/Angular 2 with html5 route style and OpenID Connect?

Comment: does it happen if you refresh the page too?

Comment: try removing `<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />` see if it works, although I am not expert in IIS ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragment values are not sent to the server, they are only handled client-side by the browser. The browser is only sending `http://mysite/callback`